# Django Template URL not recognize global value

Tags: python, django, url, django-templates

Starting from a Class based update view (Header table).
I call a Class based List View to display all the details lines created (Lines table) for my Header.
I have created a GLOBAL val that contains the key value of my Header.
Everything was working fine since I tried to insert a button to go back to my Header.
The URL works perfectly if I **hardcode** the key value of my Header.
If I try to  insert my Global variable it doesn't work.
I tried with  val(), pk=val, pk=val() but the url doesn't work. It seems that the variable is empty... Most of the time  test crash with Error message saying that Reverse for 'headfttlog_update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found.
Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'^headfttlog/update/(?P<pk>[-\w0-9_@]+)/$',
HeadfttlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='headfttlog_update'),
]
```

Views.py: in DEBUG I'm printing the val and the content is OK!

```
class DeafttlogListView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, 
      ListView):
    permission_required = 'fttlapp.view_deafttlog'

    model = Deafttlog
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Deafttlog.objects.filter(dea_fttlcode=val())
        print('Uscita Queryset Lista Deafttlog' )
        print(val())
        return queryset
```

html:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{% url 'headfttlog_update' val %}"
>Back to FTTL header</a>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add data to context object in DetailView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596961/how-to-add-data-to-context-object-in-detailview)

Comment: 1) Whatever data you want to use in the template you need to pass in the context (The template doesn't care about the global variables, view's local variables, etc.). 2) **Don't** use global variables to store data in Django unless you _really really know_ what you are doing.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I tried to do that before posting my question but I was not successfull in my attempt. I have to transmit my value from one view to another view. Header update view to lines list view and then turn back to the Header update view. I need to store and transmit the Header key to all the views. I'm surely doing something wrong but I don't understand what. Thanks for your advice on Global value, I used it because it's the only way I found to keep stored and transmit my key. If there is another way to do it I will follow it.

Comment: Each request should be _independent_ of each other, any data it needs should be fetched from some storage (mostly the database), global variables are a **bad** solution to do what you want (What happens when multiple people request that page? When there are multiple servers?)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat implemented today a cache management. Thanks for your advice